HLK tests selected for my USB device are different for Windows10 and Windows11
I have a USB device (used for Face Authentication/Hello). I wrote a user space driver for it (built on top of MSFT UVC driver: inf + a DMFT dll). In HLK Studio for Windows10, I selected the playlist for my setup: 19 tests were filtered. I ran the HLK tests and all of them passed. All good! Bellow are the selected and passed tests:
"HLKVersion":"10.0.19041.1" (2004)

DF - InfVerif INF Verification
DF - PNP Cancel Remove Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Cancel Stop Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP DIF Remove Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Disable And Enable Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Rebalance Fail Restart Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Rebalance Request New Resources Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Remove Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Stop (Rebalance) Device Test (Reliability)
DF - PNP Surprise Remove Device Test (Reliability)
DF - Reinstall with IO Before and After (Reliability)
DF - Sleep and PNP (disable and enable) with IO Before and After (Reliability)
DF - Sleep with IO During (Reliability)
Face sensor validation tests HyperVisor Code Integrity Readiness Test
Sensor Camera Driver Basic Capture Session - Preview Sink - All Mediatype
Sensor Camera Driver Basic Capture Session - Preview Sink - All Mediatype with Metadata
Sensor Camera Driver Registration, Metadata, and Dependency Test
DF - Embedded Signature Verification Test (Tuning and Validation)

In RTM HLK (10.0.26100.1), after selecting the same device and filtering the tests, a total of 54 tests resulted: 18 also present in the previous HLK run (only "Face sensor validation tests" is not selected anymore) + another 36 tests related to webcam testing. My device is not a webcam.

TDI filters and LSPs are not allowed
DF - SimpleIO stress test with IO process termination (Reliability) - trece
DF - Reboot restart with IO before and after (Reliability) - trece
Detect Malicious Software
Camera Driver Usage Indicator Manual Test
Camera Driver Test - Video Preview (View Finder) - Stream video from the default format on Camera preview stream
Camera Driver Test - Video Preview (View Finder) - Stream video from each available format from the camera's preview stream
Camera Driver Test - Video Preview (View Finder) - Stream video from all available format on the preview stream and dynamic format switching
Camera Driver Test - Video Preview (Sample Callback) - Stream video from the default format on Camera preview stream
Camera Driver Test - Video Preview (Sample Callback) - Stream video from each available format from the camera's preview stream
Camera Driver Test - Video Preview (Sample Callback) - Stream video from all available format on the preview stream and dynamic format switching
Camera Driver Test - Video Capture (Record) - Record 30 seconds of 720p Video from Capture pin to H264 file (Video Only)
Camera Driver Test - Video Capture (Record) - Record 30 seconds of 480p Video from Capture pin to H264 file (Video Only)
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestVideoCapture
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestPreview
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestPhotoCapture
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestMft0GetService
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestFrameReaderWithAllSupportedMediaFormats
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestFrameReader
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestEnumerateVideoProfile
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestEnumerateMediaFrameSourceGroupByld
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestEnumerateMediaFrameSourceGroup
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestEnumerateMediaEncodingProperties
Camera Driver System Test - MediaCapture - TestConcurrentRecordAndPhotoCapture
Camera Driver Profiles Interface APIs (Device Test)
Camera Driver Profiles Collect DevPKey Profiles (Device Test)
Camera Driver Hardware Privacy Manual Test
Camera Driver Device Test - MediaCapture - ValidatePowerlineFrequency
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Verify KSCAMERAPROFILE_VideoRecording enum all
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Verify KSCAMERAPROFILE_VideoConferencing enum all
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Verify KSCAMERAPROFILE_HighQualityPhoto, enum all
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Verify KSCAMERAPROFILE_CUSTOM enum all, photo and preview
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Verify KSCAMERAPROFILE_CUSTOM enum all
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Verify KSCAMERAPROFILE_BalancedVideoAndPhoto enum all
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CAMERA_PROFILES - Log all profiles
Camera Driver Controls Device Test - CacheUVCControl - Check that support is disabled

Question is: why, taking into account that this is the same driver on both Windows10 and Windows11, we have a different selection for the tests?
LE: I looked after "Face sensor validation tests" and it seems it applies only to Windows10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/testref/d5eac01f-7c30-4d17-8e7f-2d8d27125d96
